# update xml with xdocument in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to update a simple xml file with XDocument. here is my simple xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<message>Test test test test</message>
```

thats xml above.

when the user clicks the Button1, it reads the xml and display it on the screen. But when u click the Button2, it doesnt update the xml.

```
public partial class www_html_test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
XDocument doc;
XElement elem;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("xml/test.xml"));
    elem = doc.Element("message");
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try{

        Label1.Text = elem.Value.ToString();
    } catch(Exception ex){
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try{
        elem.Value = "test 2 test 2 test 2";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
}
```

How can I update the xml?

Comment: How do you know it isn't updating the xml? I don't see you writing the value back to the page or saving the xml file after changing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `doc.Save(Server.MapPath("xml/test.xml"))`.

At the point you change the `elem` value, it's only in memory.  To commit to disk, you must Save.

Answer (score 1):

Change the button 2 click event handler to

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try{
            elem.Value = "test 2 test 2 test 2";
            doc.Save(Server.MapPath("xml/test.xml"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
     }
```